# ERROR : The provided "html" reporter does not exist

Tags: docker, automated-tests, report, e2e-testing, testcafe

My objective is to generate HTML report using a docker image. It appears the official testcafe docker image does not have a npm package for HTML report generator. So, I started creating my own docker image.

**Dockerfile:**

FROM testcafe/testcafe:latest

USER root

RUN cd /opt/testcafe/ \
    && npm install --save testcafe-reporter-cucumber-json@latest \
    && npm install --save-dev multiple-cucumber-html-reporter \
    && npm install testcafe-reporter-html

This is the command, I am running to run the tests:

docker run --mount type=bind,source=//c/Users/sbhas1/parc-apps/tests/mo-po-dashboard,target=/tests --mount type=bind,source=//c/Users/sbhas1/parc-apps/reports,target=/reporters -w /reporters -it createefs/testcafereporter chromium /tests/season_test.js --reporter html:tests/reports/results.html

When I run this, I get error
**ERROR The provided "html" reporter does not exist. Check that you have specified the report format correctly.**

So, my questions are:
1. Where do I install npm packages in the container? is /opt/testcafe incorrect path?
2. How can I get into the container to see folder structure?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the issue by installing npm packages globally with -g option instead of locally. Now, I can generate html report with docker image.

**The final Dockerfile is:**

FROM testcafe/testcafe:latest

USER root

RUN cd /opt/testcafe \ 
    && npm install -g testcafe-reporter-cucumber-json@latest \ 
    && npm install -g multiple-cucumber-html-reporter@latest \ 
    && npm install -g testcafe-reporter-html@latest

EXPOSE 1337 1338

Answer (score 0):

Try to use below :
https://github.com/picuscreative/testcafe-reporter-html

Hope it will help you !!!!!